# Speeding up NPM package install

Tags: npm

When I deploy my app to AWS, it's copied into a new directory, so NPM will install all the same packages, during each deploy, which can take a lot of time. Most of these packages haven't changed between builds (if at all), so having it do a full npm-install seems like a waste.

My app server runs a bunch of different Node apps, so installing globally isn't an option. Instead I'd like to have the app store it's node packages in a location that isn't wiped out during deployment, but have the option to update packages as necessary during `npm install`.

Does NPM have a concept of an app-specific module directory that *isn't* located in a subfolder of an app? That way I can delete the app folder, and not have to reinstall the same packages over and over again.

I could achieve this by using symlinks, or migrating the current node_module directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you lock down your dependencies versions, NPM is likely to cache the packages. So the installation wouldn't take much longer.

If you prefer not to do this, you can install dependencies globally and link them with the `npm link` command (which is basically creating a symlink yourself!). Then, it'll be up to you update the globally installed packages regularly.

Comment: Can you globally install multiple versions of the same package?

Comment: No. Also, you can't do so with local packages, they would be overwritten.

Comment: So that's the problem with using local packages. For example, I have App1, that uses express 3.1, and another App2, that uses express 3.0. I want my appserver to run both apps, side byside, but without having to do a full NPM install, each time.

Comment: Oh, that wasn't clear from your question originally. Have you checked out the npm cache? They may back you up for such problem.

Comment: I looked at NPM cache.need a bit more time to fully grok it. Updated my question to hopefully make it clearer.